# Undoing garbage collection

Tags: error-handling, git-pull, merging-data, git-gc

Recently i was working on a project with two other guys, now i encountered an error when i was trying to pull making commits to my local work, after checking stackoverflow i was advised to to do git gc,( garbage collection), i was able to pull after that, now i have discovered that a lot of errors in my project with very old code, i would like to know if there's of reverting the garbage collection possibly any other means to get over this problem.
kind regards

i did git gc later I had errors in my project with old code, i was thinking it will clear the unnecessary objetcs

Comment: Try to checkout the main branch again. Or Maybe delete the local copy and clone again.

Comment: @Clashsoft thank you for the feedback, I will do as advised, i think something is corrupt